# Scanner warning: Resource leak : <unassigned closeble value>

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, resource-leak

I am reading a file and storing its content in a string. The code gives me a warning as : **Resource leak :**  . How do i resolve it?

```
public static String JsonFileToString(String FileName)
{
    String FileContent=null;
    try {

        FileContent = new Scanner(new File("src/main/resources/" + FileName)).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return FileContent;

}
```

Comment: Java has a naming convention: variables and method names should be written in `camelCase` (`fileContent`, `fileName`, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign the Scanner to a variable, so you can close it in the finally block.

```
String FileContent=null;
        Scanner sc = null;
        try {

            sc = new Scanner(new File("src/main/resources/" + ""));
            FileContent = sc.useDelimiter("\\Z").next();


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            sc.close();
        }
```

Comment: if the constructor of `Scanner` fails (i.e.: file not found) you'll call close() on a `null` object.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't closing the `Scanner` that you create to read the file, so the file remains open afterwards.

Assuming you're using Java 7+, use try-with-resources to ensure that the scanner is cleaned up:

```
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("src/main/resources/" + FileName)).useDelimiter("\\Z")) {
  return sc.next();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```